# nginx serving passenger on subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I got some rails 4 apps and I need them to be in /subdirectory of my domain, I am doing this with location directive, the problem is that they don't know that they are in that specific directory and all /link are going to mydomain/link instead of mydomain/app-a/link

this is the configuration that I use for one of the apps, I got it from official passenger docs

```
location ~ ^/events(/.*|$) {
    alias /home/acm/acm-events/public$1;
    passenger_base_uri /events;
    passenger_app_root /home/acm/acm-events;
    passenger_document_root /home/acm/acm-events/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Comment: I'd try `^/events(/.*|)$`

Comment: still no luck, /links go to /links instead of /myapp/links, is what I'm trying to do possible or not? :D

Comment: You may be able to extend the regex pattern to also match the app: `^/events(/.*|)(/.*|)$` or `^/events(/.*(/.*|)|)$`.  Then handle $1 and $2 appropriately in the body of location.

Comment: I thought the directive `passenger_base_uri` is the way to do this, it's hard to do what you said, since there are 3 php apps and 4 rails apps on this server.

Comment: Boot a development VM and try various configurations until everything works. Nginx is flexible, it shouldn't be a problem if you can make it work using multiple `location` directives.